# JList is showing duplicates

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a small example using Java Swing where I want to draw a sine graph on one panel and the co-ordinates of the graph in another panel. So I created a class that extends the `JFrame` then I created the `JPanel` for graph and co-ordinates. For displaying co-ordinates I am using `JList`. Now the problem is the co-ordinates are showing duplicate values. Here is my code:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    JList list;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));

        JPanel panel = new MyGraph();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        contentPane.add(panel);

        list = new JList(model);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(4);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));

        panel_1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel_1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("X - Y");
        panel_1.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JScrollPane slistScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
        panel_1.add(slistScroller);

        contentPane.add(panel_1);

    }

    class MyGraph extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int xBase = 10;
            int top = 100;
            int yScale = 10;
            int xAxis = 360;

            int yBase = top + yScale;

            g.drawLine(xBase, top, xBase, top + 2 * yScale);
            g.drawLine(xBase, yBase, xBase + xAxis, yBase);


            g.setColor(Color.red);

            int x2=0, y2=0;

            int x1 = xBase + 0;
            int y1 = yBase - (int) (10*Math.sin(0) * yScale);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                x2 = xBase + i;
                y2 = yBase - (int) (10*Math.sin(i) * yScale);
                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;
                df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                model.addElement(i +" -- " + df.format(10*Math.sin(i)));
            }
            model.addElement("------END----------");

        }

    }

}
```

Here is the output of my program:

[image]

As per my program, I have a `for loop` from angles `0 to 10` and I am adding the values to `DefaultListModel model` which is added to `JList list`.

Can someone please help me where I am doing mistake in this code?

Also even when I have this line `list.setVisibleRowCount(4);` , I was expecting only 4 records displayed to the user with a scroll-bar, but as per the output image it is not working like that.

Comment: What do you think happens when you add things to the list, then add them to the list again? (hint: it's the obvious result)

Comment: @immibis, I have single for loop in my code, so I was not expecting any duplicates. Can you please tell me where I am adding duplicates?

Comment: @immibis Hints that are too sibyllic don't help.

Comment: @user3181365 Every time the graph panel repaints itself, it calls `paintComponent` to do that, right? And `paintComponent` adds to the list. The graph panel can be repainted whenever Swing feels like it; you can't rely on when that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paintComponent` may be any number of times, for any number of reasons, try resizing the frame and see what happens.

Your paint method should focus on doing just that, painting.

You need to change the process so that the `paintComponent` becomes depend on the model, not the other way round.

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about painting in Swing.

You may also want to consider using a `ListCellRender` to render the data in the model in the `JList`, this way, you could more easily share the model and it's data.

See [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more details

Comment: Thanks for responding, so do I need to calculate the co-ordinates in a separate method and then populate my model, then use them in my `paintComponent` method for drawing graph?

Comment: Yes, more or less.  The co-ordinates should be pre-calculated before the panel is added to any displayable component, this way, it will ensure that the panel has something to paint when it is finally rendered.  Don't calculate the values more then once, unless you intend to change what is displayed

Comment: Also I wanted to change the values at later point of time using some button, but you mentioned "Don't calculate the values more then once, unless you intend to change what is displayed", can you please tell me how can I handle that?

Comment: Use your method (that calculates the values) to update the values, update model as you need to. My point is, don't call this method in your `paintComponent` method ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have separated the logic to calculate the co-ordinates from paintcomponent method. Now the duplicate issue is gone.